# Smarty - 'unable to write file... templates_c'. (smarty_internal_write_file.php:44)

Tags: php, smarty, templating

I'm using Smarty for the first time. It works fine on my laptop (MAMP) but when I try and run a basic template on my production server (Windows) I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'unable to write file C:\Inetpub\vhosts\path\to\web\root\smarty\templates_c\wrt516e53290e2095.47946913' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\path\to\web\root\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_write_file.php:44 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\path\to\web\root\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php(201): Smarty_Internal_Write_File::writeFile('C:\Inetpub\vhos...', '<?php /* Smarty...', Object(Smarty)) 
#1 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\path\to\web\root\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(155): Smarty_Internal_Template->compileTemplateSource() 
#2 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\path\to\web\root\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(374): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('test.tpl', NULL, NULL, NULL, true) 
#3 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\path\to\web\root\admin-new\admin.php(99): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->display('test.tpl') 
#4 {main} thrown in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\path\to\web\root\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 44
```

I thought this might be something to do with file permissions (not that I understand anything about how file permissions work on Windows), but when this line:

```
var_dump(is_writable('C:\Inetpub\vhosts\path\to\web\root\smarty\templates_c'))
```

prints out `bool(true)`

No idea where to go from here. Why isn't Smarty working?

Comment: Check if the template file is not accessed by another program. Better delete the content of templates_c folder, Smarty should compile new one.

Comment: I don't see how the file could be accessed by any other program as this is the very first time I've tried to use Smarty on this server. The templates_c folder appears to be empty. I deleted it and recreated it just to be sure and it made no difference.

Comment: try '$smarty->testInstall(); exit;' right after smarty initialization.

Comment: Did you manage to work this out?

Comment: Yeah, it was a problem with file permissions. I got in touch with support at my hosting company and they fixed it; unfortunately I can't tell you exactly what they did so I can't be any more helpful!

Comment: Too narrow in scope, unanswerable as "it was fixed by host, don't know how"

Comment: In my case, the user quota was over the limit, so i was getting this error. When i increased it, the the problem was solved.