# Unable to write to file

Tags: php, azure

Website is running under PHP. Using Smarty 3.1.x

Website was working fine about half a year without any changes! About 2-3 weeks ago it started to receive error logs:

```
2014-02-21 0:22:19 - CRIT --> unable to write file D:\home\site\wwwroot\/include/smarty/templates_c\bc3a2c744a52ffed3fac136ce7e5bacb0648e1ba.file.ik_home.tpl.php. Line: 74. File: D:\home\site\wwwroot\include\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_write_file.php
```

Instead of filenames, that should be created, azure hosting creates files with strange names, i.e

**wrt530644e3a6c503.24424555**

instead of

**bc3a2c744a52ffed3fac136ce7e5bacb0648e1ba.file.ik_home.tpl.php**

I can rename **wrt530644e3a6c503.24424555** to desirable **bc3a2c744a52ffed3fac136ce7e5bacb0648e1ba.file.ik_home.tpl.php** using ftp client

var_dump(is_writable('~/include/smarty/templates_c')); // bool(true)

I have found a similar question in SO [Smarty - 'unable to write file... templates_c'. (smarty_internal_write_file.php:44)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054669/smarty-unable-to-write-file-templates-c-smarty-internal-write-file-php) but it has no answer and is closed. Author just said his hosting company fixed permissions.

There is one more SO question [WindowsAzure: Is it possible to set directory permissions within the web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106179/windowsazure-is-it-possible-to-set-directory-permissions-within-the-web-config) The answer explains what happens if there is a hard drive failure, about moving my files to another rack and rebuilding instance. What should I do with permissions in this case? I don't really know if there were any failures actually :)

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved. The problem was in double back/forward slashes in the path. Changed:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\/include/smarty/templates_c\bc3a2c744a52ffed3fac136ce7e5bacb0648e1ba.file.ik_home.tpl.php
```

To

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot/include/smarty/templates_c\bc3a2c744a52ffed3fac136ce7e5bacb0648e1ba.file.ik_home.tpl.php
```

Why Azure stopped handle double slashes in path?!